# Как в цикле for использовать .text()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Мне надо при нажатии кнопки пройтись про всем значениям инпутов и запушить их в массив.

```
var dateArray = [];
var date = $(".input-group input");
for (var i = 0; i <= date.length - 1; i++) {
    dateArray.push(date[i]);
}
```

В данном коде я просто пушу весь инпут,а вот юзать `date[i].text()` нельзя.
Может кто-то знает как бы это сделать? Ну или какой-то другой подход к данной задаче

Comment: А может `.val()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используйте `$.map()`, либо добавляйте в `.each()`

```js
//var result = $.map($("input"), function(i){ return $(i).val(); });

var result = $("input").map( function(){ return $(this).val(); }).get();

//var result = $("input").map( (i,e) => $(e).val() ).get();


console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input value="1">
<input value="2">
<input value="3">
```

Comment: Все круто!!Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Тут задание немного изменилось и думаю,что вы понимаете,как его решить https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/801925/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8