# Как значения с блоков передавать в виде массива с объектами?

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

```
var priorityArray = $('input[name=priority]:checked', '.priorityForm').map( function(){ return $(this).val(); }).get();
var textArray = $(".description").map( function(){ return $(this).text(); }).get();
var dateArray = $(".input-group input").map( function(){ return $(this).val(); }).get();
```

Таким образом я выводил какие-то конкретные значения в одном массиве,но мне надо кидать это все в один массив примерно с такой структурой:

```
[
  0: {
    priority: "",
    text: "",
    deadline: ""
  }
]
```

И так к каждой элемент в массив кидать

Comment: html покажите как выглядит. этоведь список какой-то где у каждого элемента есть дескрипшен и инпут? ну или что то подобное?

Comment: https://codepen.io/mikepavlyuk/pen/MVJqrB?editors=1000

Comment: такой блок один на странице, или при чем тут циклы/массивы тогда?

Comment: Это я ангуляром добавляю блоки,вот сейчас обновлю код на codepen,чтоб вы поняли,там может быть сколько угодно блоков,зависит от того,сколько юзер добавит https://codepen.io/mikepavlyuk/pen/MVJqrB

Comment: http://prntscr.com/itpbd8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас на странице потенциально содержатся блоки `.task_block` внутри которых нужные вам элементы. действовать нужно соответственно, перебрать все такие блоки,  и вытащить нужные сведения для каждого.

что-то вроде

```
var result = [];
$(".task_block").each(function(idx, v){
    var data = {
        description: $(v).find(".description").text(),
        priority: $(v).find("input[type=radio]:checked").val(),
        .....
    }; 
    result.push(data);
});
```

можно и через `map` но для данной задачи это как-то не кажется подходящим решением.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!Просто нету слов)))